# Java overloading and inheritance method selection

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

lets research following code:

```
public class App {

    public static class A {

        public void doSmth3(long a) {
            System.out.println("This is doSmth3() in A...");
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {

        public void doSmth3(int a) {
            System.out.println("This is doSmth3() in B...");
        }
    }

    public static void test(A a) {
        a.doSmth3(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       test(new B());
        new B().doSmth3(3);
    }

}
```

ouput:

```
This is doSmth3() in A...
This is doSmth3() in B...
```

from my side 2 lines in main should provide same result but result is different.

My opininion `This is doSmth3() in A...` should output twise because it is overloading.

Please explain output

Comment: 3 is an int, this means the method with the int parameter will be called. If you change it to 3L it will be a long, then the method with the long parameter will be called (always the 'most fitting' method will be called if you overload it.

Comment: IMO the reason for the confusion was your naming conventions... this is really simple code but it is hard to read because you are reusing numbers and letters....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple: when the Java compiler sees the call to `a.doSmth3(1)` inside `test(A)`, it can only possibly compile it to a call to `A#doSmth3(long)`, which is the *only* method available. Note that `B#doSmth3(int)` is an *overload* of `A#doSmth3(long)`, not an *override*.

Answer (score 1):

Class `A` contains the following method:

```
public void doSmth3(long a)
```

Class `B` contains the following methods:

```
public void doSmth3(long a) // Inherited from class A
public void doSmth3(int a)  // This is an overload of doSmth3
```

When you call `a.doSmth3(1);`, a is referenced with type `A`. Hence, it has to call method with the `long` argument. The other method using `int` is not available for an object referenced as `A`.

When you call `new B().doSmth3(3);`, the object is referenced as a type `B`. It contains both methods. Since you pass a `int` value, it uses the method with the `int` argument.

Answer (score 0):

When you overload, method selection is based on the type or parameters, and the decision to implicitly cast types is made at compile time. Therefore, `test(new B());` runs `doSmth3(long)` because that is the only method available to `A` and

```
public static void test(A a) {
    a.doSmth3(1);
}
```

has to choose a method available to `A`.

But when you call `new B().doSmth3(3);` you have all methods of `A` and `B` to choose from and `doSmth3(int)` in `B` is a better fit for an `int` literal than `doSmth3(long)`. So that why you print from `B`, because your input is an `int`.